# CMake: circular dependency on different targets

Tags: cmake

My project has a CMakeLists in a libs/ directory like this:

```
add_subdirectory(foo)
add_subdirectory(bar)
```

With bar depending on foo.
I recently added new functionalities to foo, and appropriate tests. However those tests need functionalities from bar. This means I currently need to run CMake twice to be able to compile.
Is there a way to get around this issue or am I stuck with re-running cmake multiple times?

Is there a way to declare my dependencies in a specific way maybe? ie right now I do this:

```
add_library(${BAR} ${SRC_FILES} ${PUBLIC_HEADERS} ${PRIVATE_HEADERS})
```

which means that linking against `${BAR}` in a test (located in the foo module) will expand the variable to an empty string. Can I tell CMake that this should be a target and not just a target name?

Comment: Not sure what do you want to express, but `add_library` accepts (aside from the first argument) only source **files**, not *targets*. For adjust dependencies between targets, use `target_link_libraries` or `add_dependencies`. "However those tests need functionalities from bar." - a test which checks functionality of 2 or more libraries looks more like integrate tests, so should be declared outside of directories with those libraries. Add such tests with `add_subdirectory()` in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, so both `foo` and `bar` targets will be visible for them.

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_library.html), my usage of add_library is correct; the first argument is the target name. I didn't know about `add_dependencies`, it looks better than using `target_link_libraries` when adding, well, a dependency. However I highly doubt it's going to solve my issue.

You are probably right that my code structure is bad. To give some context, I am writing some computer vision code where it is hard to test the lower-level bricks by themselves. foo.a.test depends on bar.b which depends on foo.b.

Comment: Could you provide more code of your project: What is under `foo` directory? A library target? What is the name of that target? What does "bar depending on foo" mean? Linking (`target_link_libraries`) or some other dependency? What does "tests need functionalities from bar" mean? Depending on the `BAR` variable, your `add_library` call could be correct, but you doesn't describe that variable. The phrase "Can I tell CMake that this should be a target and not just a target name?" has no sence: in CMake the targets are referred only by their names.